# Ajax Select with preselected value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, select

I have a little problem with my ajax script, script works fine when you're selecting the value in dropdown yourself. But when you click submit it takes the value and puts it in GET.

And when you go to the "http://script.domain?prov=1" (which triggers selected value in dropdown) ajax script its not working (i think it because on.(change) and when its the value is pre selected it not changed so script doesn't react ).

So i need the script to automatically run when the page is loaded and check the #prov dropbox value.

here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/gfzd5aa1/1/

HTML

```
<form action="" method="get">
<label for="prov">Provincia: </label>
<select name="prov" id="prov" class="form-control">
<option value="0">Selecciona la provincia</option>
    {% for provincia in provincias %}
     <option value="{{ provincia.id }}" {% if get.prov == provincia.id    %} selected  {% endif %} > {{ provincia.name }} </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

<label for="zona">Provincia: </label>
<select name="zona" id="zona" class="form-control">

</select>
</form>
```

There the "Provincia" select field triggers ajax to populate "Zona" select.

```
$('#prov').on('change', function() {
var self = $(this);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/casas/public/ajax-prov',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { id: self.val() },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        var $zona = $("#zona");
        $zona.empty(); // remove old options

        $("#zona").append('<option value="0">Seleciona la Zona</option>');
        $.each(response.prov, function(i, state) {

            $("#zona").append('<option value="'+ state.id +'">' + state.name + '</option>');

         });

    }

});
});
```

My javascript skills are very basic and if you could help me out make it work, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: Can you console.log(response) at your request and to paste here what is the answer from your ajax-prov

Comment: When using it manually it returns a object but when used with the GET 'prov' variable it does returns nothing. its like the ajax is not triggered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending a `prov` variable with your get request but insted `id`.
Try this:

```
...
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/casas/public/ajax-prov',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { prov: self.val() },
...
```

EDIT:
Miss understood the question so the final response is

```
$( document ).ready(function() { if ($('#prov').val() != "0") $('#prov').change() });
```

Comment: I know, but i want the GET "prov" variable to trigger select the value in the first dropbox and the value from that dropbox to trigger the ajax. like it work when u select field in dropbox manually. Look up the jsfiddle i add html there it makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "i want the GET "prov" variable to trigger". Also, why do you have this URL "http://script.domain?prov=1" on your question? I run your code and it makes the request.

Comment: Let me explain, the ?prov="value" triggers that the option in select #prov what has the value == to ?prov='value' is selected. But when you get to the link with the ?prov='value' the ajax is not triggered. because the value is already preselected. and it doesnt populate the #zona dropdown.

and it only works when you change the dropdown value manually. and thats my problem

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ check the note on that documentation and see if it helps. You need to fire the event yourself if you change a select value using Javascript.

Comment: thats why i'm looking for a way to have ajax check the #prov value automatically  without having to be fired.

Comment: What about when the document is ready check if the value of prov is different from 0 and fire the change event: $( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($('#prov').val() != "0") $('#prov').change()
});